# SVG Animation not working on Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

working on a circular pie chart like animation. Works perfectly on Chrome but does not animate on Firefox while it doesn't show at all on safari.

Do you know what the problem is?

https://codepen.io/jamalfaiez/pen/zYwVKPq

```
<div class="circle_anim rndm_01 rndm_rotate_03">
    <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 285 284">
      <g class="circles">
        <circle cx="142" cy="142" r="142"></circle>
        <circle cx="142" cy="142" r="137"></circle>
        <circle cx="142" cy="142" r="137"></circle>
        <circle cx="142" cy="142" r="137"></circle>
        <circle cx="142" cy="142" r="137"></circle>
        <circle cx="142" cy="142" r="137"></circle>
        <circle cx="142" cy="142" r="137"></circle>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `display: flex` from `.circle_anim` restored most of the visualization for me.

```css
.circle_anim {
  position: relative;
  width: 285px;

  /* display: flex; */

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```